# Как отключить CSRF валидацию в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Как отключить CSRF валидацию в laravel?

Answer (score 5):

Для 5.2:

в app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php можно добавить переменную **$except**
и там указать пути для которых не нужно проверять токен.

```php
protected $except = [
    '/unprotected/*'
    ];
```

кроме того, если нужно отключить совсем, томожно сделать это через app/Http/Kernel.php :
в массиве **$middlewareGroups** в нужном вам Middleware закоментировать строку:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

Для **GET**-запросов **CSRF**-защита отключена по умолчанию (см. **handle()** в *vendor/*...*/VerifyCsrfToken.php*). Маршруты же для **POST**-запросов выглядят примерно так: **/unprotected/profit** или **/unprotected/trifle**. Т.е. в нашем случае код следующий

```
protected $except = [
    '/unprotected/*',
    '/unprotected/profit',
    '/unprotected/trifle',
];
```

для **POST**-запросов */unprotected/profit*, */unprotected/trifle* и запросов, начинающихся с */unprotected/*.